# Why is an outlet box outside of the wall?

Tags: electrical, wiring, inspection

[image: jutted outlet box]  I'm considering putting an offer in on a house and am questioning this outlet prior to being able to do a home inspection.  Is there any reason to be alarmed that this outlet is boxed outside of the wall?  What are the reasons that the electric would be ran like this?  I don't see any obvious signs to answer my question in the basement below the outlet.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see in the fuzzy pic, someone wanted a double-gang outlet where there was a single-gang box. They apparently didn't want to cut the wall at all.

There's probably no concern as far as safety, but pop an outlet tester into it to be sure.

Comment: So you would assume that I'd be able to cut out the wall and install a double box in the wall to remove the protrusion?   The box is in the living room where a tv would be located so that would make sense wanting four plugs there, all other boxes in the house are single gang.

Comment: You might be able to, but I would not *assume* that you can as there may be a stud in the way (especially being right under the window there). If you are handy you could probably do it anyway. A fairly safe assumption might be that you could remove the 2-gang box and go back to a single-gang box inside the wall, with a single duplex receptacle.

Comment: A [2 gang old work box](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-2-Gang-34-cu-in-Heavy-Wall-Old-Work-Box-BH234R/100177871) should work the original box is usually nailed to the stud. knock the old single gang out and you can still have 4 outlets. There should be nothing to worry about that it was surface mounted.

Answer (score 0):

That outlet protrusion may very well be one of these adapter units plugged into a normal single wide electrical outlet. Here are representative examples of what I am talking about. A center screw typically goes into the original outlet cover screw hole to hold the adapter against the wall.

[image]

[image]

If it is one of these and you do not like the protrusion just remove it and  install a conventional cover plate on the wall outlet.